# Using "Than" vs "Than that of" and "Any" vs "Any other" in a sentence

Tags: difference, adjectives, determiners

> Ray is the better that **any other** student in the class.
>   Ray is better than **any** student in the college.

When do we use ANY and **ANY OTHER** in a sentence comparing things, place, etc.?

Comment: What do "Than" and "Than that of" have to do with your question?

Comment: Anyway as far as I know "any other" stand for plural while "than that of" stands for singular. "any" and "any other" are interchangeable. **Ray is the better that any other student in the class.** is correct and **Ray is better than any student in the college.** is also correct.

Comment: **This painting is better than that of Kate's.** is correct and **This painting is better than Kate's.** is also correct.

Comment: You can also say, **"This painting is better than that Kate painted"**

Comment: "Ray is the better that any other student in the class" and "This painting is better than that Kate painted" are definitely not correct.  The correct phrasings would be "Ray is better than any other student in the class" and "This painting is better than that which Kate painted."

Comment: why is it incorrect to say "This painting is better than that of Kate's" ? please provide a reason.

Comment: "This painting is better than that of Kate's" is wrong because it's using two different ways to show possession at the same time.  Something can be *Kate's painting* or it can be *the painting of Kate*, but you don't use both constructions in the same sentence like "the painting of Kate's".

Comment: I think we're comparing a painting painted by a person is better than kate's painting .